# ¿Cómo añadir imágenes en Ionic 2?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic2

Buenas.

La verdad es que me da un poco de verguenza abrir esta pregunta pero no entiendo que narices está pasando o si estoy pidiendo un imposible.

Quiero hacer una galería de imágenes dentro de mi app. Para ello he almacenado las imágenes en

> src/resources/img/

Y para acceder a ellas desde el html de un componente hago lo siguiente:

```
<ion-img src="../../resources/img/imagen1.jpg"></ion-img>
```

Si yo hago shift + click sobre la ruta, me abre la imagen correctamente. Sin embargo al hacer ionic serve en la consola, no me muestra las imágenes. Me da un 404:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

¿Alguna idea de que está pasando o de que hago mal?. No encuentro nada por internet por más que busco sobre el tema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede tratar lo siguiente en el arbol de direcctorios de su proyecto, a la misma altura de `app` es muy probable que tenga un directorio con el nombre de `assets` cree o copie dentro de este, el contenido que desea usar, en este caso su `imagen1.png` algo asi:

```
app/
assets/img/imagen1.jpg
//..
```

.

```
<ion-img src="../assets/img/imagen1.jpg"></ion-img>
```

o

```
<ion-img src="assets/img/imagen1.jpg"></ion-img>
```

el usar uno u otro dependera desde donde se este llamando y del tipo de configuracion que tenga la vista, si se ha modificado la raiz ect.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Funciona perfecto!